# Why is YouTube showing me notifications that I disabled?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I receive these absolute rubbish notifications. Not in email, but in YouTube.

I only really want notifications where people have replied to me.

[image: Google notifications screen shot]

Here are the settings I have ticked/unticked:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/settings

[image: settings screen shot]

So I see no reason why I am getting notified of all this nonsense. These people aren't addressing me directly or sharing content with me directly.

Comment: This is either a flat-out bug or a usability bug. Most Google services have a "Send Feedback..." command for reporting bugs. Try that.

Comment: G+ comments have been mostly divorced from YouTube. Is this still an issue?

Comment: @AʟE. yeah, I think so, as recently  I had to choose "mute post" where somebody commented, i'm sure not replying to me, but I got a notification.  I don't know if they have G+ written on those comments. I'll look out for how the comments appear next time and reply to you re that.

Comment: @AʟE. yeah, looks like it, as recently I had to choose "mute post" where somebody commented, i'm sure not replying to me, but I got a notification. here's a pic   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWIKS.png

Answer (score 1):

As of writing, I think there's no option to change it, and the best thing to do is just to ignore it. You can tighten the notifications such that you get an email then you can know somebody replied to you (which you already have).  But you can't tighten the notifications that appear in that window. So just ignore it, don't read all the junk there.

If you get an email and it links you there then fine, you could reply to that comment (if you see it within the junk in that window).